# Unable to do a PATCH on w REST API through JAVA

Tags: java, rest, api, patch

I want to call an API with different method :

The post and get are ok using HttpClient

I'm unable to do the PATCH and delete methods, does anyone implemented such thing ? and how ?

Post Method 1

```
public static String sendPost(String requestURL, Map<String, String> headers, String postParameters,
        boolean withProxy) throws IOException {

    HttpURLConnection con = createProxyHttpConnection(requestURL, withProxy);
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setDoOutput(true);

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
        con.setRequestProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());

    }
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(postParameters);
    String response = IOUtils.toString(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");

    wr.close();
    con.disconnect();
    return response;

}
```

Post Method 2

```
public static HttpResponse sendPostBis(String requestURL, Map<String, String> headers, String payload,
        boolean withProxy) throws IOException {

    StringEntity sEntity = new StringEntity(payload,
            ContentType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(requestURL);
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
        request.addHeader(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());

    }
    request.setEntity(sEntity);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    return response;

}
```

I'm using method 1 for POST with params and the Method 2 for POST with json body

**Error message** *(the same that I'll receive if I change method to POST instead of PATCH in SoapUI)*

```
{"error":"No route found for \u0022POST \RESOURCE","message":"No route found for \u0022POST RESOURCE"}
```

Comment: Are you using any frame work?

Comment: Post your code for the post method

Comment: I'll edit my code, and no i'm using no framework (it's an appium app, and i'm bypassing a step than can't be automated on mobile) @SamuelRobert

Comment: @SamuelRobert : code adde :)

Comment: You must enable PATCH method at the server side to do PATCH request...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :

Change `HttpPost request = new HttpPost(requestURL);` by `HttpPatch request = new HttpPatch(requestURL);`

Also there was problem on my url (https), so thanks @Ivan Jadric

Answer (score 1):

Without providing any code, my best guess would be that the network over which you are trying to make those PATCH and DELETE requests has blocked those HTTP verbs and thus you are unable to make them. Most network security tools consider any verbs other than GET and POST to be unsafe and do therefore blacklist them

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in fact through SoapUI I'm able to do PUT, DELETE and PATCH, it's through java that i'm facing problem, I just added the code

Comment: Judging by the error message, it is not an error with Java per se, but looks more like a 404 error. Add some logs to see the full path where the request is being made, and if it the URL is clean and good, then maybe the server does not have POST, PATCH mapping for that resource